# EF: Create/Remove relation from Many-to-Many relations when `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` and `ProxyCreationEnabled` are disabled on DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

1. Knowning `Foo.Id` and `Bar.Id` how can I create their relation without loading the entities from the DB.

   ```
   class Foo {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public Lst<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
   }

   class Bar {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public Lst<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Also this configuration are disabled in `DbContext` constructor:

   ```
   Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
   Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
   Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   ```
2. And how it is possible to remove the relationship?

---

Example:

```
using (var ctx = new DbCtx())
{
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    ctx.Database.Log += Console.WriteLine;

    var foo = new Foo {Id = 1, Bars = new List<Bar>() };
    var bar = new Bar { Id = 3, Foos = new List<Foo>() };

    // This approach wont work, as AutoDetectChanges are disabled
    ctx.Foos.Attach(foo);
    ctx.Bars.Attach(bar);

    foo.Bars.Add(bar);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can I define relation here, without changing the configuration.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear ? can you provide more info ?

Comment: @Sampath, i have update the question with the example I want to avoid, as it makes extra request to the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, have found the solution and here is the helper method:

```
static void ChangeRelationship<T1, T2>(
    IObjectContextAdapter ctx, 
    T1 a, 
    T2 b, 
    Expression<Func<T1, object>> getNavigationProperty,
    EntityState state) where T1: class
{
    ctx
        .ObjectContext
        .ObjectStateManager
        .ChangeRelationshipState(
            a,
            b,
            getNavigationProperty,
            state
        );
}
```

And using it in my example from the question:

```
using (var ctx = new DbCtx())
{
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    ctx.Database.Log += Console.WriteLine;

    var foo = new Foo {Id = 1, Bars = new List<Bar>()};
    var bar = new Bar { Id = 3, Foos = new List<Foo>() };

    ctx.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    ctx.Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    // create
    ChangeRelationship(ctx, foo, bar, x => x.Bars, EntityState.Added);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // remove
    ChangeRelationship(ctx, foo, bar, x => x.Bars, EntityState.Deleted);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: There are more answers along these lines at StackOverflow. It does the job, but it's a mega leakage of a persistence implementation into application logic. It's no longer possible to simply add objects to a collection. IMO, when the many-to-many pattern with a hidden junction class causes problems you should turn to a visible junction class. Having that, you could simply add/remove `FooBar` junction objects. Alternatively, what's wrong with only one `DetectChanges` call just before saving?

Comment: Actually, yes, it is the persistence layer, many people use `DBContext` and `SaveChanges` in business domain layer, but I find this way wrong. And personally I find the explicit state changes are much better and cleaner, then when `AutodetectChanges` is enabled. And finally, it is much more better for performance.

Comment: That's why I said *application logic*, not business logic. There's always a place where objects are added/removed from `DbSet`s. Now you'll always have to keep in mind that in this specific case you can't do that. My recommendation would be to turn to a visible junction class to eliminate this difference. Like I read the other day, assume that the next guy on the project is an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you wanted to add Bar object to an existing Foo entity without making a lookup for Foo entity.

Let say, you have Foo (id = 1) already exists. Wanted to add new Bar (id = 100) entity to it.

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var bar = new Bar() { Id = 100 };
    var foo = new Foo() { Id = 1 }; // Only ID is required

    context.Foos.Attach(foo);
    bar.Foos.Add(foo);

    context.Bars.Add(bar);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Correct, thank you,  but when the context has disabled "AutoDetectChanges" and "ProxyCreation" would the ".Add (bar)" detect the new relationship? And another part, how do I delete the relationship?

Comment: Yes. The dbcontext will do the job even with the disable options. For deletion, follow the Evan's direction. Should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work, as the `AutoDetectChanges` is disabled on the context.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is possible. Here are the steps:

(1) Start by creating two entity instances with just PK specified and attach one of them (for instance `foo`) to the context:

```
var foo = new Foo { Id = fooId };
var bar = new Bar { Id = barId };
ctx.Foos.Attach(foo);
```

(2) Set the second entity collection to a new list containing the first entity (i.e. "create" the relation):

```
bar.Foos = new List<Foo> { foo };
```

(3) Mark the second entity as follows:

*(A) To add relation:*

```
ctx.Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Added;
```

*(B) To remove relation:*

```
ctx.Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

(4) Mark the second entity as unchanged:

```
ctx.Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

And that's it!

Once you call `ctx.SaveChanges();`, the relation will be added or removed from the junction table.

**Update:** While the above works (actually my original solution of attaching the second entity with the "original" collection and then simulating modification also works if we call at the end `DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` explicitly), I should admit that the `ObjectContext` solution you found looks much more natural (it's strange that such functionality has not been exposed via `DbContext`), so my personal vote goes there.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I made an example, and this doesn't work, as the precondition was, that the `AutoDetectChanges` are off. That's why just calling `,Add(foo)` wont detect new relation. Is there any another way to do this?

Comment: Are your sure you have set `ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` before first `Attach`? As when I comment this line out, then your example works perfect.  I'm using EF 6.0, but I don't think the version matters, as the whole idea about `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is to remove any side effects on entities and collections. So when we do `bar.Foos.Add(foo)`, it should perform only usual IList actions, with no EF mixins.

Comment: @tenbits Please excuse me, and disregard my previous comment. I'm pretty sure I did set it as requested, but at some point looks like I deleted it accidentially. I'm pretty sure there is a solution, will update the answer when restore it.

Comment: Yeap, it happens) But anyway, thank you for your help, and also for your time. The solution here is to use `ObjectStateManager` directly, see my answer. Cheers, Alex

Comment: @tenbits Yeah, interesting. The old good `ObjectContext` stuff :) Well, I've posted my little `DbContext` tricks in case you are interested. Cheers.