# EF many-to-many update not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have read over several other questions about this, but I haven't been able to get it to work for me.

I'm using EF Code First, I have two entities Room and Equipment with a many-to-many relationship. It's correct in the DB with an intermediate table that contains a foreign key to both the Room and Equipment tables. However, I haven't been able to get an insert to work.

```
            var room = roomService.FindById(roomId);
            var equipment = service.FindById(equipmentId);

            //do I need to do both of these?
            room.Equipment.Add(equipment);
            equipment.Rooms.Add(room);

            db.SaveChanges();
```

This doesn't work at all. I have also trying using `Attach`  to attach both the relevant entities to the context based on advice in other questions but it just seems to stop the code from running. Also, I tried manually change the `EntityState` to `Modified` and that didn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: `room.Equipment.Add(equipment);` should be all you need.

Comment: That was my first thought, but nothing happens when I do it. No row is added to the intermediate table.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708439/ef-create-remove-relation-from-many-to-many-relations-when-autodetectchangesen

Comment: How are you getting a reference to db? I would have to assume db is a context shared by the roomService and service classes?

Comment: Weird. I've successfully done this before with a many-to-many in EF6 code first. Were you still calling `db.SaveChanges();` after the `.Add()` line?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, but what if you get the `room` with `Include(r => r.Equipment)`? At least it would demonstrate that the mapping is OK.